# Take user inputs in ranger file manager

Tags: python, linux, file-manager

I want to create a custom command for ranger, however, I have no Idea about how to get an user inputs since it freezes when I use the traditional way `input()`.
I already spent hours googling it but nothing worthy so far.

```py
class user_input(Command):
    def execute(self):
        file = self.fm.ui.console.input('user input...') # '.input()' doesn't exist
        self.fm.notify(file)
```

I'd really appreciate the help.